# PHP in meta tags not working?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I'm very new to programming so bear with me... My site is based on Wordpress, so I have an index page that says `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php include('pagecontent.php'); ?>`... My header.php contains what you'd expect and pagecontent.php is actually a pretty complex page that grabs several variables from a database (for instance, `$result->properties->name`).  I'm starting to integrate Facebook Connect plugins (the like button and comment box), and when I put PHP in my `<meta>` tags in the `<head>`, Facebook doesn't recognize the value of `$result->properties->name`... IF my php files were all the same, the relevant code would look like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
[REMOVED THE DIV TAG HERE]<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<?php
echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . $result->properties->name . ' on Name of Site"/>';
echo '<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>';
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>';
echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="Name of Site"/>';
echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="698461078"/>';
echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . $result->properties->description . '"/>';
?>
</head>
<body>
[MOVED DIV TAG DOWN HERE]<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like href="http://www.sitename.net/?sg=' . $sg_id . '&task=0" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="true" action="recommend" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
</body>
```

I tried to be as complete as possible to avoid guesswork :P  This code gives liked pages the title " on Name of Site" instead of "Name of Movie on Name of Site".  Why isn't it able to grab the variable?  Is there something I can do to modify the meta tags from within pagecontent.php?  Please don't be afraid to state the obvious things!  Many thanks ;)

Comment: why are you putting divs in your <head>?

Comment: Where is `$result` being populated?

Comment: @tylerl can you show us where you getting your `$result` from?

Comment: You'd be better off leaving the `<meta` bits "outside" of php and just echoing out the values you want to fill in. This'd make things much more legible.

Comment: @michaelrobinson Google Chrome's Element Inspector says the same thing Facebook does - `<meta property="og:title" content=" on Name of Site">` @b_dubb @mkilmanas The <div> was always below the meta tags... But I moved it in front of the `<fb:like>` tag and there was no difference.  @JackOfAllTrades @atno $result is being populated by an S3 database - the code that grabs the value is about 20 lines before the `<fb:like>` tag.  So it's effectively after the meta tags and before the like button... Is this the issue?

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, I'd tried that first - no dice :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your comments above you say:

> $result is being populated by an S3
>   database - the code that grabs the
>   value is about 20 lines before the
>    tag. So it's effectively
>   after the meta tags and before the
>   like button

Move the code that grabs the value *before* the `meta` tags.

Comment: +1 Yes. Things must be defined before you can use them. "Before", literally.

Comment: I feared this was true... And I'm trying to move the PHP function into the `<head>` but so far I'm doing something wrong there :(  Isn't there some way to modify the `<meta>` tag later on in the page?  I just feel like there's gotta be a nicer way to have dynamic `<meta>` tags... right?

Comment: Why do you want to modify the `<meta>` tags later in the page? It's a top to bottom language, so, yes, you must define it, before you can use it. However, if you show us the code that grabs the value, and the reason why you want it to be after the metas, maybe we can come up with a solution. :)

Comment: Thanks for helping, everyone!  I got it working now - I had to move the code that pulled data from the database before the `<meta>` tags, which had to be in the `<head>`.  HTML5 doesn't require `<meta>` tags to be in the `<head>` but I guess Facebook's linter is using a previous standard, and it's still bad practice either way given the fact that most people are on outdated browsers.